# Удаление лишнего текста из TextField

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

Расскажу что надо, нужно чтоб при нажатии на Button, из TextField удалялись лишние символы.
Чтоб в самом коде было указано что if (label.text == <50) *((Или как то так))* то удаляется все, что после 50 символов. Мне именно нужен не ограничитель, а удаление после нажатии на button, я буду очень благодарна если вы напишите уже готовый код) Пожааалуйста.)

Comment: ElenaAngel - это что, твинк ElenaDemon? В любом случае, Елена, тут на ХК не любят вопросы, в которых совсем-совсем просят прислать готовое решение. Что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: Я от того пароль забыла :D, не получается удалить текст... Мне нужно чтоб удалялось все лишние, если больше чем 50 символов в textfield. Допустим если там было написано - "1234567890", а мне нужно чтоб можно было ввести только 5, и при нажатии на button, становится вот так "12345", все лишние удаляется... Как-то так :D не знаю, понял или нет?

Comment: Вопрос решен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе, который ловит событие кнопки нужно добавить:

```
    NSString *string = [yourLabel text];
[yourLabel setText: [string substringToIndex: 51]];
```